# Nodejs Passportjs question about which strategies to use for React frontend with facebook, google or email login

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js

As title have said, I'm trying to to build a simple web app with 3 different ways of logging in and React as frontend. Two of which are Google and Facebook oauth and the last is just simple email and passport that the users that have registered. My question is which strategies should I use? My guess is im gonna need passport-facebook and passport-google-oauth and passport-jwt. But I might be wrong. Do I even need passport-local at all since my frontend is React?

Answer (score 1):

You could use both strategies. It really depends on what you're working on. Personally I always use Google strategy and then store the accessToken or other informations in the passport session. I personally prefer to use Google approach because the 80% of what we develop makes a massive use of Google Apis scope (i.e. Calendar Api, Drive Api). Google strategy is useful to me because as soon as I have the google profile datas I could take advantage of that infos to pass to some Google Apis service. I.E.:

```
const getGoogleDriveResources = async (userToken, driveId = 'root') => {
  const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2();
  oauth2Client.setCredentials({
    'access_token': userToken, // This is the accessToken from passport google authtentication
  });

  const drive = await google.drive({
    version: 'v3',
    auth: oauth2Client,
  });
```

I hope this can be useful to you